# Recurring payment in Adyen

Tags: php, adyen

I am trying to initiate a recurring payment in Adyen but I am unable to figure out how to do so. I have tried sending a request up receipt of payment results:

```
$request = array(
                'amount.currency' => $this->currency,
                'amount.value' => $sepaSubmission->amount,
                'merchantAccount' => $this->merchantAccount,
                'recurring.contract' => "RECURRING,ONECLICK", 
                'reference' => $sepaSubmission->psp_reference, 
                'shopperEmail' => $account->email, 
                'shopperReference' => $account->email,
                "selectedRecurringDetailReference" => "LATEST",
                "skinCode" => env('ADYEN_SKIN_CODE'),
                );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, env('ADYEN_USERNAME') . ":" . env('ADYEN_PASSWORD'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.adyen.com/hpp/pay.shtml");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($request));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
```

I get the following error: Error: Skin null does not exist
I have verified a valid skinCode is included.

I am using SepaDirect as payment.

I have also just tried attaching the above fields to the initial payment submission form I am using and they are essentially ignored, the payment is processed as a one off.

Any assistance would be appreciated, I have been combing through the documents for several days to get this going to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to redirect to the skin in order to do a followup Sepa transaction. This because you are making the call to "https://test.adyen.com/hpp/pay.shtml".

Sepa direct debit can be processed directly via the API, there is no need to send the shopper to the HPP

You can do the following:

```
$request = array(
            'amount.currency' => $this->currency,
            'amount.value' => $sepaSubmission->amount,
            'merchantAccount' => $this->merchantAccount,
            'recurring.contract' => "RECURRING", 
            'reference' => $sepaSubmission->psp_reference, 
            'shopperEmail' => $account->email, 
            'shopperReference' => $account->email,
            "selectedRecurringDetailReference" => "LATEST",
            "shopperInteraction" : "ContAuth",
            );



 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, env('ADYEN_USERNAME') . ":" . env('ADYEN_PASSWORD'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v25/authorise");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($request));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
```

Please note the change in URL, the removal of the skincode and the addition of "shopperInteraction" : "ContAuth", and the removal of one click in 
recurring.contract' => "RECURRING",

So when you want to charge a shopper again, you just do this call from your end, there is no need to send him to the HPP.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,
Andrew